# IUPAC name for [CoSO4(NH3)4]NO3

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, coordination-compounds

What is the correct IUPAC nomenclature for the coordination compound $\ce{[CoSO4(NH3)4]NO3}$?

Comment: I significantly edited your question and removed unnecessary parts (I hope this is OK); still, this looks like a homework-type question. Please include your ideas or suggestions to avoid closing.

Comment: Thank you so much. This wasn't a homework question. I was stuck on  something, thus I thought of getting it clarified, but soon I figured out my mistake. So I AM actually trying to remove this question. Apologies for that, as I am a newbie here. So it's taking a bit time to figure out how does this work :)

Comment: Sure, no prob. It's just the [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) policy which is applied to the questions where no attempt has been shown. Others are not supposed to answer these questions, and they are typically end up closed. If you want, you can [edit] your thoughts in (or just the name of the compound you think is correct), so that others can actually help you with this:)

Comment: @Advdtii and if you have figured out the issue, you can include an answer to your own post to help future readers.

Answer (score 3):

The answer I came up with is tetraamminesulphatocobalt(III) nitrate .

Comment: It's "sulfato" and not "sulphato".

Comment: @Loong Actually "sulfate" is preferred by IUPAC and "sulphate" is from British English. (Courtesy: wikipedia)